# How to use Jersey's Response.ok(inputStream) method properly

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to optimize the following code which is used to produce a stream containing random data of a given length that is streamed from the server to the client:

```
@GET
@Path("/foo/....")
public Response download(...)
        throws IOException
{
    ...
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // This method writes some random bytes to a stream.
    generateRandomData(baos, resource.length());

    System.out.println("Generated stream with " +
                       baos.toByteArray().length +
                       " bytes.");

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

    return Response.ok(is).build();
}
```

The code above look ridiculous as it won't work for large data, I know, but I haven't found a better method for writing to the stream of the response. Could somebody please show me the proper way of doing it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think this won't work for large data? `Response.ok(is).build()` looks as easy as it gets.

Comment: Because for large files I would have to write the file in-memory, before writing it to the `InputStream`.

Comment: But that is not a problem of JAX-RS but of how your data is generated.

Comment: Tichodroma, you are indeed right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own InputStream implementation defining `read` method to return random data :

```
public class RandomInputStream
        extends InputStream
{

    private long count;

    private long length;

    private Random random = new Random();


    public RandomInputStream(long length)
    {
        super();
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public int read()
            throws IOException
    {
        if (count >= length)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        count++;

        return random.nextInt();
    }

    public long getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(long count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public long getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(long length)
    {
        this.length = length;
    }

}
```